# Nearest point to origin of a hyperplane by Lagrange multiplier

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, vector-spaces, lagrange-multiplier

Find the point on the hyperplane $x^Tc = β $that is closest to the origin by Lagrange multiplier method.

What is hyperplane and how we obtain its origin ! I need a serious hint !!

Comment: A hyperplane is like a plane in 3D Euclidean space, but in higher dimensions, so is one dimension smaller than the space itself, and can be identified by the direction orthogonal to it and a point within it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You need solve this problem
$$
\min_{x\in D}\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2,\qquad D=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n~:~x^{T}c-\beta=0\}.
$$
For this, define the Lagrangian by
$$
L(x,\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2-\lambda(x^{T}c-\beta).
$$
Imposing the condition $L_{x}(x,\lambda)=0$, we have $x=\lambda c$. As $x$ must belong to $D$ we have that $\lambda=-\beta/\|c\|^2$. So $x=-\frac{\beta c}{\|c\|^2}$.
Remark: Check all the details that I did not do.